# Setting min-vh-100 to a DIV's that's already in a BODY of min-vh-100

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-5

I am trying to set a DIV's min-height to 100% or 100vh of the container.

But:
setting `min-height:100%` to the DIV isn't working and
adding class `min-vh-100`to the DIV is giving it's height more than the parent DIV.

```
<body class="min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column bg-primary">

<header class="p-3 bg-success">
    Header<br/>
    Content
</header>

<div class="container flex-grow-1 p-0 bg-secondary">

    <div class="d-flex flex-column"><!-- What do I have to do here to set this DIV's height to 100% of parent DIV ? -->

        <div class="flex-grow-1 p-3 bg-danger">
            Main Content that's need to fill up vertical space
        </div>
        
        <div class="p-3 bg-warning">
            Bottom Content for Main
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
  
<footer class="p-3 bg-info">
    Footer<br/>
    Content<br/>
    &copy; 2022 Bootstrap
</footer>

</body>
```

This is what I want :

[image: expected div min-vh-100]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>    
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Footer at Bottom when content is not page-full</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column bg-primary">

<header class="p-3 bg-success">
    Header<br/>
    Content
</header>

<div class="container flex-grow-1 p-0 bg-secondary">

    <div class="d-flex flex-column">

        <div class="flex-grow-1 p-3 bg-danger">
            Main Content
        </div>
        
        <div class="p-3 bg-warning">
            Bottom Content for Main
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
  
<footer class="p-3 bg-info">
    Footer<br/>
    Content<br/>
    &copy; 2022 Bootstrap
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to solve this *without* the use of JavaScript.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>    
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>flex child as a flex container with 100% height of parent flex container</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>
{
    let body = document.body;
    let html = document.documentElement;

    let body_height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,  html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
    let header_height = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].offsetHeight;
    let footer_height = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].offsetHeight;

    document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].style.height = (body_height - (header_height + footer_height)) + "px";

});
</script>
</head>
<body class="min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column bg-primary">

<header class="p-3 bg-success">
    Header<br/>
    Content
</header>

<main class="container p-0 d-flex flex-column">

    <div class="flex-grow-1 p-3 bg-danger">
        Main Content
    </div>
    
    <div class="p-3 bg-warning">
        Bottom Content for Main
    </div>

</main>

  
<footer class="p-3 bg-info">
    Footer<br/>
    Content<br/>
    &copy; 2022 Bootstrap
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```